# Parse header (<h1> -- <h6> tags) to ordered list, using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm making a table of contents, in the style of an ordered list, based on the header structure, such that:

```
<h1>lorem</h1>
<h2>ipsum</h2>
<h2>dolor</h2>
<h3>sit</h3> 
<h2>amet</h2>
```

becomes:

- lorem

  - ipsum
  - dolor

    - sit
  - amet

This is how i'm currently doing it:

```
$('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').each ()->
  # get depth from tag name
  depth = +@nodeName[1]

  $el = $("<li>").text($(this).text())
  do get_recursive_depth = ()->
    if depth is current_depth
      $list.append $el
    else if depth > current_depth
      $list.append( $("<ol>") ) unless $list.children().last().is('ol')
      $list = $list.children().last()
      current_depth += 1
      get_recursive_depth()
    else if depth < current_depth
      $list = $list.parent()
      current_depth -=1
      get_recursive_depth()
```

which *works*, but it seems like it lacks elegance. Is there a smarter / faster / more robust way to do this?

Comment: Is that coffeescript?

Comment: it is, but it's not really a 'coffeescript question' as much as it's a jquery question.

Comment: Why is `dolor` not indented at the same level as `sit`?

Comment: You can use `(':header')` selector for this instead of `h1, h2, h3, ...`

Comment: @elclanrs because it's an `h3` while `dolor` is `h2`

Comment: @JanDvorak Actually, it's the exact opposite. ;)

Comment: @JanDvorak: It was just edited by OP.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery emplementation:

```
var $el, $list, $parent, last_depth;
$list = $('ol.result');
$parent = [];
$parent[1] = $list;
last_depth = 1;
$el = 0;
$('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').each(function () {
    var depth;
    depth = +this.nodeName[1];
    if (depth > last_depth) {
        $parent[depth] = $('<ol>').appendTo($el);
    }
    $el = $("<li>").text($(this).text());
    $parent[depth].append($el);
    return last_depth = depth;
});
```

Maybe someone will come in handy))

Answer (score 1):

Here's the way I would do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/edi9999/cNHPW/

Instead of traversing the DOM up and down, I store the parent for each h1..h6 tag, and I than know where I have to append the current li element. `$el` and `last_depth` are global variables (That's why I put the line `$el=0` outside of the function)

```
$list=$('ol.result')
$parent=[]
$parent[1]=$list
last_depth=1
$el=0

$('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6').each ()->
    # get depth from tag name
    depth = +@nodeName[1]
    if depth>last_depth
        $parent[depth]=$('<ol>').appendTo($el)
    $el = $("<li>").text($(this).text())
    $parent[depth].append $el
    last_depth=depth
```