# JS/jQuery - Create multi-dimensional array (or JSON structure) out of heading elements

Tags: jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

Let's assume an HTML structure like this:

```
<div id="relevantHeadings">
    <h1>First Heading</h1>
    <h2>First Subheading</h2>
    <div>
        <!-- for clarification that the headings are not necessarily siblings -->
        <h2>Second Subheading</h2>
    </div>
    <h1>Second Heading</h1>
    <h1>Third Heading</h1>
    <h1>Fourth Heading</h1>
    <h2>Third Subheading</h2>
    <h1>Fith Heading</h1>
</div>
```

EDIT: The headings are not necessarily siblings of each other.

What i need is this:

```
'menu': {
    'level':[
    {
        'label': 'First Heading',
        'level' :[
        {
            'label': 'First Subheading'
        },
        {
            'label': 'Second Subheading'
        }]
    },
    {
        'label': 'Second Heading'
    },
    {
        'label': 'Third Heading'
    },
    {
        'label': 'Fourth Heading',
        'level' :[
        {
            'label': 'Third Subheading'
        }]
    },
    {
        'label': 'Fith Heading'
    }]
}
```

My actual code is a lot more complex with more attributes than `label` and more dimensions / levels as well.

I started quite a few tries so far but i can't figure out how to properly push subarrays into one item of an array:

```
this.allHeadings = $('#relevantHeadings').find('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');

this.obj = {};
this.obj['level'] = [];

this.allHeadings.each(function(i) {

    if($(this).is('h1')) {
        thiz.obj['level'].push(this);
    } else if($(this).is('h2')) {
        // create and push this one into thiz.obj['level'][i-1]['level']
    }

});
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/17419747

Comment: not quite what i need. I probably should've mentioned this earlier - the script to builds the navigation is allready finished. It build the navigation from a JSON-structure. Now i need to write a script that translates my DOM into that JSOn structure.
The link provided skips the whole JSON process which is not possible for me

Comment: Sure, but it's trivial to adapt the script to use an JSON tree instead of a DOM tree.

Comment: as i said: my use case is much more complex. Most of the time the JSON structure is given by some Server-side script and i simply have to process it. The option to build a navigation out of the DOM is simply an option to the current script, which makes it necessary to build a JSON structure first. (Huge project, huge company, can't change the premise :-( )

Comment: No, building a json structure from the DOM is *not* more complex than building a navigation structure from the DOM. The algorithm is the very same.

Comment: i get what you're saying. I didn't mean to say that building a JSON structure is more complex. I meant to say the usecase of mine is not the same or as easy as the one in the provided link to just not build said JSON structure. That said: i agree that the algorithm should be the same. I'm going to try some stuff with that code and get back to you. Thanks for the link and help!

Comment: Is it possible that there will be h1 then h3 rather than h1 then h2?

Comment: @Ignas for several reasons: no.

Comment: @Bergi so after creating my ugly code (see my answer) i can see now how the code on your provided link will improve mine. I'll try to do this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got it. It's the most ugly code and if someone smarter than me has a little time, i'd love if you would clean that up and post it as an answer so i can accept it.
I'm sure there is a way to make this much shorter.

This code is only for `h1` to `h3` but you get the idea.

```
var prevObj;
var h1 = 0;
var h2 = 0;
var h3 = 0;

var buildNavigation = function(containerSel) {

var thiz = this;
this.container = $(containerSel);
this.allHeadings = $(container).find('h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6');
this.obj = {};
this.obj['level'] = [];

this.allHeadings.each(function(i) {
    myLoop(this, i);
});

return this.obj;
}

var myLoop = function(element, index) {
var thiz = this;
this.ele = element;
this.index = index;

if($(this.ele).is('h1')) {
    var innerObject = {
        label: $(ele).text()
    }
    thiz.obj['level'].push(innerObject);


    prevObj = thiz.obj['level'][h1];
    h1++;

} else if($(ele).is('h2')) {
    if(prevObj.level) {

    } else {
        prevObj['level'] = [];
    }

    prevObj.level.push({
        label: $(ele).text()
    });

    prevObj2 = prevObj['level'][h2];
    h2++;

} else if($(ele).is('h3')) {
    if(prevObj2.level) {

    } else {
        prevObj2['level'] = [];
    }

    prevObj2.level.push({
        label: $(ele).text()
    });

    prevObj3 = prevObj2['level'][h3];
    h3++;

}
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  buildNavigation('#relevantHeadings');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/Iber/a8Kgj/ for testing check console.

Here's the code:

```
function findNodes(step, $this) {
    var selector = null;
    var object = {};
    object['level'] = [];
    if ($this) selector = $this.next('h' + step);
    else selector = $("h" + step);

    selector.each(function () {
        var innerObject = {
            label: $(this).text()
        };
        var nextHeading = findNodes(step + 1, $(this));
        if (nextHeading.level.length > 0) {
            innerObject.level = nextHeading;
        }
        object['level'].push(innerObject);
    });

    return object;
}
console.log(findNodes(1));
```

Comment: while i think your code is brilliant (seriously), there are some flaws.
1. $this.next doesn't cover more than one `h2` after each `h1`
2. $this.next only works, if all headings are siblings, this is why i started by collecting all headings first. (i should've made that clear in the question)
3. the final array has a minor bump:
`{"level":[{"label":"First Heading","level":{"level":[{"label":"First Subheading","level":{...`
This: `level: { 'level': [...]}` is wrong. Should be `level: [ {label..}, {label..}]`